# Can't get a JSON object in response to an Ajax request with wp_ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, headers, json

I have a problem with WordPress and Ajax.

This is my JavaScript part (I trimmed it a bit):

```
var posts = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action: 'myAjaxFunc' },
    done: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
}).responseText;

$.each(posts, function() {
    $('#someSelect').append( $('<option</option>').text(this.name).val(this.id) );
});
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
function myAjaxFunc() {

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'post_type'        => 'my-post-type',
        'post_status'      => array( 'publish', 'draft' )
    ) );

    $list = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $list[] = array(
            'id'   => $post->ID,
            'name' => $post->post_title,
            'link' => get_permalink( $post->ID ),
        );
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode( $list );
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc' );
```

The script gets the Ajax response from admin-ajax. Unfortunately the console throws an error when it gets to the `each` statement in the JavaScript code... it says:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4' in Array".
```

If I do a console.log of my "posts" var I get a string 'Array'. No matter how I pass the `$list` variable in PHP it will always return a string. The query returns posts elsewhere, so it's not empty. I tried without `json_encode`, with and without declaring header, using `wp_send_json()`, putting `ob_clean()` before echoing the array, putting the array into an array... But it always gets into `ajax` as a string `Array` and `each` cannot cycle through it.

This should be a very simple thing and I can't understand why it's not working. I don't have other JavaScript or PHP errors or warnings and everything else runs fine.

Comment: What do you see when you go to http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=myAjaxFunc

Comment: Any progress on your question? Could you please follow up?

Comment: oh... this is from 5 months ago... I did answer to my own question by the way the next day I posted it, using bits of BODA82 answer - I just didn't marked it as the correct answer; @toscho added his follow up much later yesterday I can't verify if his answer is also good now, it makes sense though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[BODA82's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168692/cant-get-a-json-object-in-response-to-an-ajax-request-with-wp-ajax/168694#168694) helped, but eventually I realized that I should have replaced `responseText` with `responseJSON` method in my JavaScript code. In the example below I was storing the Ajax response results in a variable. I didn't know there was a specific method to get the response in JSON. In a such way the object/array with `get_posts()` results is returned correctly and not as a string:

```
posts = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action : 'getHotelsList' },
    done: function(results) {
        // Uhm, maybe I don't even need this?
        JSON.parse(results);
        return results;
    },
    fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log( 'Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown );
    }
   }).responseJSON; // <-- this instead of .responseText
```

Note to self, but also general advice: if you can't fix something in the evening it's a sign you should go to bed, read a book, and count stars. An answer will be found the next morning, the earlier the better :D

Answer (score 2):

Almost there with your PHP function. No need to set the header. (Edit: Also, assuming `get_posts()` is actually returning results.)

```
function myAjaxFunc() {

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'ASC',
        'post_type'        => 'my-post-type',
        'post_status'      => array( 'publish', 'draft' )
    ) );

    $list = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $list[] = array(
            'id'   => $post->ID,
            'name' => $post->post_title,
            'link' => get_permalink( $post->ID ),
        );
    }
    echo json_encode( $list );
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjaxFunc', 'myAjaxFunc' );
```

And your Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "action=myAjaxFunc",
    success: function(results) {
        var posts = JSON.parse(results);
        console.log(results);
        $.each(posts, function() {
            $('#someSelect').append( $('<option></option>').text(this.name).val(this.id) );
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
    }
});
```

Comment: When you save some data using JSON.stringify() and then need to read that in php. The following code worked for me. json_decode( html_entity_decode( stripslashes ($jsonString ) ) );

Answer (score 2):

There is a way out. Use `complete` instead of `success` or `done`:

```
posts = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action : 'getHotelsList' },
    complete: function(results) {
```

And try to remove `async:false` if the problem persists.